# How to Filter by item_name in GA4 Funnel Exploration When It's Nested in an Array?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am working on setting up funnel explorations in Google Analytics 4 (GA4) and I'm facing a challenge with filtering funnel steps by the item_name parameter, which is nested within an items array in an eCommerce event.

GA4 seems to support top-level parameters for funnel steps, but I'm not sure how to handle nested parameters like item_name.

Does GA4 funnel exploration allow for filtering based on values within an array of objects? If not, what are the best practices for tracking specific items through funnel steps in GA4?

Thanks in advance!

I tried to create a funnel and on one of the steps I've added:
Event = purchase (this one alone shows all of the purchases).
item_name = #the-item-name (which I can see in other reports, and I see the tag firing)